# Connect MySQL 3.23 hosted on Linux Server via MySQL Workbench 5.2 on Windows

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I've a mysql database with version 3.23 installed on linux server.

When i try to use the database using sql yog, it will connect.But when i try to connect to the database using mysql work bench installed on windows xp, i will get an error. 
Screen shots are below :

1. When i tried to connect mysql with the help of SQL YOG,
   [image: SQL Yog Connectivity- Status SUCCESS]
2. When i try to connect mysql with MySQL workbench
   [image: mysql work bench error]

I used Putty to check whether SSH port 22 is listening or not, it is listening.. I can see the terminal.. an i checked host of root login...
[image: root login previligers]

I tried connecting with the help of SSH, i didnt get the solution... I am not able to track where i am getting wrong...

Can any one help me out???

Thanks in advance...

Regards,
Anoop Pete

Answer (score 2):

Your server version is just [not supported](http://www.mysql.com/support/supportedplatforms/workbench.html):

> MySQL Workbench fully supports MySQL Server versions 5.1 and above. It
>   is also compatible with MySQL Server 5.0, but not every feature of 5.0
>   may be supported. It does not support MySQL Server versions 4.x.

Sadly, MySQL 3.23 is almost 12 years old.

Comment: I am eager to know how SQL YOG 6.5 connects MYSQL 3.23 without using any SSH. do you know???

Comment: Yes... MySQL workbench uses tunneling to connect to MYSQL hosted on Linux, but how SQL YOG has done connectivity. They accepted only Basic Info of database such as Host Name, Port, User Name, Password without using SSH port... I am confused of their process...

Comment: MySQL Workbench accepts HOSTNAME, PORT NUMB, SSH PORT NUMBER, Then MYSQL Host Name, Port Name, Credentials of MySQL to connect... But SQL Yog Accepts only HOSTNAME, Post Number, Credentials of MYSQL... Regardless of Hosting Machine's OS, they have done the connectivity...

Comment: Connecting through a SSH tunnel is not mandatory. As far as I know, it isn't even a builtin feature. If you have some information about regular MySQL port being disabled, you haven't shared it with us.